# How do I put my food objects (ovals) into an ArrayList, so that I can remove it upon collision with my other fish objects?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, collision

How do I put my food objects (ovals) into an ArrayList, so that I can remove it upon collision with my other fish objects? I've looked up some online tutorials, but I'm not sure how to call the "radius"/size of the fish within my food class to measure the distance for the collision detection.

This is my code for my food class right now:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import processing.core.PVector;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Food {

private int size;
private PVector pos, speed;
private Color color;
private double scale; 

public Food (int x, int y, int size, Color c) {
    this.size = size;
    this.pos = new PVector (x,y);
    this.color = c;     

}


public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillOval((int)pos.x, (int)pos.y, 15, 15);

}
```

and this is my code for my fish class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

import processing.core.PVector;

public class Fish {

private static final int PI = 0;
private static final Polygon Polygon = null;
private int size;
private PVector pos, speed;
private Color color;
private double scale;
private double scaleone;
Food [] foodList = new Food[10];        

public Fish(int x, int y, int size, int speedx, int speedy, Color c) {
    this.pos = new PVector(x,y);
    this.size = size;
    this.speed = new PVector(speedx,speedy);
    this.color = c;
    this.scale = 2;// give value to the scale variable from the top; 
    this.scaleone = 1;  
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    AffineTransform af = g.getTransform(); 
    g.translate((int)pos.x, (int)pos.y); 
    g.rotate(speed.heading());
    g.scale(scale,scale);
    if (speed.x < 0) g.scale(1, -1);

    int [] xp = {-20, -50,-50};
    int [] yp= {-15,-25,-5};


    //DRAW TAIL 
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    Polygon p = new Polygon();
    p.addPoint(xp[0], yp[0]);
    p.addPoint(xp[1], yp[1]);
    p.addPoint(xp[2], yp[2]);
    g.fillPolygon(p);

    //drawBody
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillOval(-size/2, -size/2, 45, 30);

    //eye
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(0, -size/3, size/10, size/10);
    g.setTransform(af); // this is popMatrix();

}



public void move() {
    pos.add(speed);
}

public void checkCollision(Dimension panelSize) {
    if ((pos.x < size/2 * scale) || (pos.x > panelSize.width - size/2 * scale)) speed.x *= -1;
    if ((pos.y < size/2 * scale) || (pos.y > panelSize.height - size/2 * scale)) speed.y *= -1; 

    }   
}
```

Comment: Your title and your question seem inconsistent - please try to explain more clearly.  Do you have some error?